# Sinatra: Compressing images from tempfile via MiniMagick before sending to API

Tags: ruby, api, sinatra, temporary-files, minimagick

I am trying to compress an image before sending a request to an API using this code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'unirest'
require 'mini_magick'
require 'json'

require 'open-uri'

get '/' do

    File.read('public/views/index.erb')

end

post '/' do
    Unirest.timeout(5)
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(params['user_image'][:tempfile])
    image.resize "600x400" 
    response = Unirest.post 'https://search.craftar.net/v1/search',
            parameters: {
                token: "703eb042371c49f0",
                image: image                                        
            }

    body = response.body

    url = body['results'][0]['item']['url']

  redirect url

end
```

When it runs to get the result, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError at /
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tempfile.rb in open
  def open
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb in open
      name.open(*rest, &block)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_magick-4.3.6/lib/mini_magick/image.rb in open
      Kernel.open(path_or_url, "rb") do |file|
server.rb in block in <main>
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(params['user_image'][:tempfile])
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
          proc { |a,p| unbound_method.bind(a).call }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in compile!
          proc { |a,p| unbound_method.bind(a).call }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in []
            route_eval { block[*args] }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block (3 levels) in route!
            route_eval { block[*args] }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in route_eval
      throw :halt, yield
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block (2 levels) in route!
            route_eval { block[*args] }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in process_route
        block ? block[self, values] : yield(self, values)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in catch
      catch(:pass) do
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in process_route
      catch(:pass) do
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in route!
          returned_pass_block = process_route(pattern, keys, conditions) do |*args|
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in each
        routes.each do |pattern, keys, conditions, block|
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in route!
        routes.each do |pattern, keys, conditions, block|
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in dispatch!
        route!
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in invoke
      res = catch(:halt) { yield }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in catch
      res = catch(:halt) { yield }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in invoke
      res = catch(:halt) { yield }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in dispatch!
      invoke do
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in call!
      invoke { dispatch! }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in invoke
      res = catch(:halt) { yield }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in catch
      res = catch(:halt) { yield }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in invoke
      res = catch(:halt) { yield }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call!
      invoke { dispatch! }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
      dup.call!(env)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb in call
        status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb in call
        app.call env
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb in call
        status, headers, body = app.call(env)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb in call
        result or app.call(env)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb in call
        result or app.call(env)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb in call
        status, headers, body        = @app.call(env)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/logger.rb in call
      @app.call(env)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb in call
      status, header, body = @app.call(env)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
        call_without_check(env)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
      env['sinatra.commonlogger'] ? @app.call(env) : super
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb in call
    status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb in call
      @app.call(env)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/show_exceptions.rb in call
      @app.call(env)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
      result, callback = app.call(env), env['async.callback']
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
      @stack.call(env)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in block in call
        synchronize { prototype.call(env) }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in synchronize
          yield
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
        synchronize { prototype.call(env) }
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb in service
        status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb in service
      si.service(req, res)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb in run
          server.service(req, res)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb in block in start_thread
          block ? block.call(sock) : run(sock)
```

If this doesn't work, how can I extract an image uploaded by a user that is temporarily stored and compress it to the specific requirements that the API needs.

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

The code in image.rb is calling Kernel.open on the tempfile. This calls open from open-uri.rb, which calls open on it if the object responds to that. A tempfile responds to open, but does not accept the 'rb' param open-uri delegates from image.rb to it.

I think the easiest solution is to wrap the tempfile into a normal file and to go from there:

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(File.new(params[:user_image][:tempfile]))
```

The code still fails, but the error (`unrecognized option -to-ary'`) in MiniMagick I think is unrelated.